# Why did they say the pageant was their first live show?

Tags: plot-explanation, hairspray

Multiple times throughout the movie *Hairspray*, they make numerous references to the Corny Collins show being broadcast live. So why, on the day of the Ms. Teenage Hairspray pageant, do they say it's their first live show?

Specifically the 2007 version of *Hairspray*.

Comment: Are you after the one from '88 or '07 (or both and it doesn't matter)?

Comment: Sorry, specifically the '07 movie.I haven't seen the '88 one, so it could also be in that one.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Although the action at the start of the movie makes it clear that the show is live.  Looking at script it seems to be that it is the first time that the show has had a live studio audience.